# Sum after groupBy in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document in mongodb like this

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5552f1ea3726845811c33ffe"),
"date" : "13-05-2015",
"User" : 107,
"allRecipt" : [ 
    {
        "recipt_Number" : 1,
        "amount" : 123,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5552f1ea3726845811c34000")
    }, 
    {
        "recipt_Number" : 2,
        "amount" : 566,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5552f1ea3726845811c33fff")
    }
],
"__v" : 0
}
```

Another document

```
 {
"_id" : ObjectId("5552f24d3726845811c34003"),
"date" : "13-05-2015",
"User" : 108,
"allRecipt" : [ 
    {
        "recipt_Number" : 1,
        "amount" : 2345,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5552f24d3726845811c34005")
    }, 
    {
        "recipt_Number" : 2,
        "amount" : 800,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5552f24d3726845811c34004")
    }
],
"__v" : 0
}
```

3 rd document

```
   {
"_id" : ObjectId("5552f24d3726845811c34003"),
"date" : "13-05-2015",
"User" : 108,
"allRecipt" : [ 
    {
        "recipt_Number" : 1,
        "amount" : 200,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5552f24d3726845811c34005")
    } 
],
"__v" : 0
}
```

What i want to do here is match the documents with a date requested then group by documents having same "User" field and then get a total for each user of amount.I have used query like this :

```
Recipt.aggregate([
        {$match: {'date': req.params.date}},
        {
            $group:{
                _id : "$User",
                "total": { 
                    "$sum": "$allRecipt.amount" 
                } 
            }
        }

    ], function (err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
    });
```

It is grouping  by user but shows total : 0
Result :

```
     [{_id:108, total:0},{_id:107, total:0}]
```

But what i want is

```
     for 108 total be 2345+800+200  and for 107 total be 123+566
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### UPDATE

For newer MongoDB versions:

```
const pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "date": "13-05-2015" } },
    { "$addFields": {
        "total": { "$sum": "$allRecipt.amount" }
    } },
    { "$group":{
        "_id" : "$User",
        "total": { 
            "$sum": "$total" 
        } 
    } }
];
```

---

You need to include an [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator pipeline stage after the match pipeline step as it deconstructs the `allRecipt` array field from the input documents to output a document for each element. Each output document is the input document with the value of the array field replaced by the element. You can then do the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group) operation on the separated/deconstructed documents to get the total receipt amount of the documents grouped by the `User` key:

```
var pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "date": "13-05-2015" } },
    { "$unwind": "$allRecipt" },
    { "$group":{
        "_id" : "$User",
        "total": { 
            "$sum": "$allRecipt.amount" 
        } 
    } }
];

Recipt.aggregate(pipeline)
      .exec(function (err, result){
          if(err){
              console.log(err);
              return;
          }
          console.log(result);
          res.json(result);
    });
```